# SharePoint Search Center (People Search)

Tags: sharepoint-search, search-center

### problem

I create few sites collection and one search center when I search for people result shows nothing.I have no clue where i am doing wrong.

### image 1

[image]

### image 2

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't have User Profile Service configured properly for this.

Here's how to check: [SharePoint 2013 People Search Result Empty](https://penainformatika.wordpress.com/2014/07/23/sharepoint-2013-people-search-result-empty/)

If you need full instructions, you can read this tutorial:

[How to Configure People Search in SharePoint 2013](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Roji.Joy/how-to-configure-people-search-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Let me know if you need help or have more questions.

Comment: Thanks @jpollar I follow your given second link and my issue resolved. I just allow mysites to crawl by create new crawl rule. (Y)

Comment: Excellent! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

There are tons of things can go wrong but moving forward. please validate these prerequisites details [MSDN article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh582311.aspx).

- A Search service application must be running in the farm.
- A Managed Metadata service application must be running in the farm.
- User profile synchronization must be configured in the farm. If this has not been done yet, at a minimum you must complete the following procedures that are described in Synchronize user and group profiles in SharePoint Server 2013:

  - Phase 0: Configure the farm
  - Phase 1: Start the User Profile synchronization service

**Setup People Search**
After validating all the prerequisites start Setting up people search from this [MSDN article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh582311.aspx#Anchor_1).